# Button that triggers Facebook Messenger with specific text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger

I am trying to create a Messenger button on my rails app in order to simplify the way users can share their sponsor link.

So it would be a button that opens Facebook in a new tab/window with a pre-written message like: 'use this link and get 10% off on myapp.com !'

The user would only need to type the person it wants to send the message to.

so far I have set up the Facebook SDK

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'XXX',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.1'
    });
  };



  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

but from that point I don't know how to create the button that would trigger the action described above. How can I do that ?

Comment: There is no way to do that. At most you could implement the Send button or Send dialog to let your web app users send a link to their friends as a message - but you can not specify the text of the message for them.

Comment: OK I see, thank you for your help @misorude ! then How can I set up the send button to send a link ? i found this in the doc: [click here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages#url) but I have no clue where I have to implement this in my own code.

Comment: What you linked to there has nothing to do with the Send button, that is part of the Messenger API (and that is for communication between a user and a page only.) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog are the ones I’m talking about.

Comment: OK got it ! exactly what I was looking for. thank you very much !

Comment: send button is deprecated since February 5th 2018.

Comment: Ah, didn’t notice that so far. But the dialog seems to be still available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as @misorude mentionned in the comments, there is no possibility to share a pre-written message; but it possible to share a link this way:

initialise Facebook SDK:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '01234',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.1'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

then create a button:

```
<button class="fb-msg-button" onClick=sendDialog()>
  <i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></i>
  <span class="sponsor-btn--text">Messenger</span>
</button>
```

finally write the corresponding js function:

```
  function sendDialog() {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      link: 'http://www.mylink.fr/',
    });
  }
```